# How to get/read a flag value in Chrome's about:flags?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How does one programmatically read the value of chrome://flags/#enable-panels with javascript from a chrome extension?

Comment: Your title is more generic than the question in your body. There is no satisfying answer for the title, but there is one for the other question, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630789/detect-if-chrome-panels-are-enabled

Comment: @RobW, the title takes precedence, of course.  I've bookmarked your other solution as a workaround in case this question does not have a better, more generic, solution as of 2015.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to open a panel but the user does not have them enabled, it will just be show as a popup window. You can check for support like so:

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url:"panel.html", type:"panel", width: 400, height: 600
  }, function(window) {
    if (window.type === "panel") {
      console.log("Panels enabled.")
    } else {
      console.log("Panels disabled.")
      chrome.tabs.create({
        url:"chrome://flags/#enable-panels"
      }, function() {
        alert("Please enable panels.")
})  }  }  })
```

Answer (score 0):

The settings for all the flags are in the plain-txt file `Local State` in your User Data directory. For example:

```
C:\Users\FooUser\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Local State
```

You can then use `XMLHttpRequest` to get that file, like so:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","file://C:/Users/FooUser/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Local State",false)
xmlhttp.send();
console.log(xmlhttp.response);
```

And you'll get something like this:

```
{
  …
  "browser": {
    "enabled_labs_experiments": [ "disable-gpu-vsync", "extension-apis", … ],
    …
  }
  …
}
```

Comment: But, I will not know the name of the user or even the path of the user dir.

Comment: And it would be _insane_ to think Chrome will allow to open an arbitrary `file://` URL.